# MySQL select to detect mutually exclusive row conflicts within groups

Tags: mysql, select

With the following sample data, I want to create a query that can find where item/desc is duplicate and their respective data fields are not mutually exclusive.  Meaning... there can be only 1 data value in column for a given combination of item/desc.

Sample table records:

```
id  | item  |  desc | data1 | data2 | data3
----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
1   |   1   | cat   |   a   |       |
2   |   1   | cat   |       |   b   |
3   |   1   | cat   |       |   e   |
4   |   2   | dog   |   a   |       |          
5   |   2   | dog   |       |   h   |   f
6   |   3   | apple |   k   |       |   m
7   |   3   | worm  |   a   |   g   |   x
8   |   4   | rock  |   p   |       |   s
9   |   4   | rock  |       |       |   s
10  |   4   | rock  |       |   t   |   z
```

Expected query result:

```
 item  |  desc 
-------+-------
   1   | cat                (because of conflict in data2 with b & e)
   4   | rock               (because of conflict in data3 with s,s & z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
select distinct 
item,
`desc`
from
table
group by item, `desc`
HAVING count(distinct data1) > 1 or count(distinct data2) > 1 or count(distinct data3) > 1
```

Comment: Might need backticks for desc column since it`s a reserved word

Comment: I understand the answer, but not that it was accepted.  The `count()`s should be `count(distinct)`.

Comment: @Gordon there ya go so it matches his req

Answer (score 1):

You could do simple count aggregation and `HAVING` clause to achieve this.

```
SELECT `item`,
   `desc`,
   COUNT(`data1`) AS `data1count`,
   COUNT(`data2`) AS `data2count`,
   COUNT(`data3`) AS `data3count`
FROM table
GROUP BY `item`, `desc`
HAVING `data1count` > 1
   OR `data2count` > 1
   OR `data3count` > 1
```